# Cin Integers with Space Issue

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, operators

```
vector<int> var;
    int numb;
    for(;;){
        cin>>numb;
        var.push_back(numb);
        if(numb!='\n'){
            break;
        }}
    insertionSort(var);
    for(int i=0;i<var.size();i++){
        cout<<var[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

When I input e.g. 1 2 3, it only takes the first value when I hit enter. Any solutions?

Comment: if you enter several arguments - cin take one per invocation. you can use std::getline() and parse ints if you really need to input them as you do

Comment: I entered 3 integers with spaces and it only took the first number. Whats wrong with the code?

Comment: You break whenever the input number isn't 10 (`'\n'`). 1 is not 10.

Answer (score 2):

You can use iterators for the standard input the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> var( std::istream_iterator<int>( std::cin ),
                          std::istream_iterator<int>() );

    for ( int x : var ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or you can use a loop like this

```
int numb;

while ( cin >> numb ) var.push( numb );
```

As for your code then you can not read the new line character such a way as you are using. The new line character is a white space that is skipped when the operator << is used.

Comment: Could the code I am using be changed in a way I can read the new line character whn Im pressing enter?

Comment: @Testermoon01 The new line character is not text representation of a number. I think you are not going to store it as a number in the vector. You could use standard function std::getline and then use std::istringstream to read integers from the string.

Comment: Oh, now I understand why it doesnt read the enter key. Adding to that I really cant use getline or istringstream or even iterators

Comment: @Testermoon01 You can use the loop I showed in the post. In this case you have to append the input with EOF. For example in Unix ut is the combination ctrl + d.

Comment: Sorry also that, I cant really use Ctrl+D or even Z. I only need to pressed enter to terminate it. The instructions said so

Comment: @Testermoon01 You can use a sentinel value as for example 0 or -1 or some other and check whether the value was read.

Comment: Already did that and I just really need to pressed the enter key to terminate the loop.

Comment: @Testermoon01 Yes, you need to enter the sentinel value and press the enter key. The loop can look like while ( cin >> numb && numb != SENTINEL_VALUE ) { /*...*/ }

Comment: What if the user don't know that value is need to be entered? And the program will just accept integers in a single line then terminated with enter?

Comment: @Testermoon01 It is your task to say the user what is the sentinel value. Otherwise use getline as I already mentioned.

Comment: You're right but our prof wants us to sort a line of integers without limit and  it will only be terminated when enter is pressed.

Comment: @Testermoon01 Class std::string in fact has no limit. The limit is set by the available memory.:)

Comment: I dont even know how you could even stay with me because I have so many demands. My classmate just finish this kind of program and wont share how he did it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cin >> a >> b >> c; in this case, but to put it simply, using cin once will only read into one variable. If you need to read more than one variable then a better option would be to read in a string and extract them from there.